# Python - Comparing content of text files

Tags: python, text, raspberry-pi3

I want to compare the content present in text files with the content present in a collection of text files.

For example,

**TEXT FILE 1**(output):

```
123abc
```

**TEXT FILE 2**:

```
567xyz
```

**TEXT FILE 3**:

```
123abc
```

Here, **TEXT FILE 1** matches with **TEXT FILE 3** such that I want to display "*YOU MAY ENTER*" on the LCD.
But in the case that there wasn't any match, I want to display "*YOU CANNOT ENTER*" on the LCD.

I am using Raspberry Pi for this project of mine.

Comment: Your topic should be more general like "How to compare one text file against others in Phyton"

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as:

```
files_path = ["path_of_file1", "path_of_file2", "path_of_file3"]
files_text = []
flag = False
for path in files_path:
    with open(path) as f:
        text = f.read()
        files_text.append(text)
total_files = len(files_text)

for item in range(total_files):
    index = item + 1
    for it in range(total_files - index):
        if files_text[item] == files_text[index]:
            flag = True
        if index < total_files:
            index = index + 1
if (flag):
    print "YOU MAY ENTER"
else:
    print "YOU CANNOT ENTER"
```

Comment: Thanks for the code... But its always showing "You can't  enter"  even when there is a match. Is there some corrections i can do in the code to eliminate this bug??

Comment: thanks for pointing out bug, the index was not reset after second loop completed, now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

[filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) should do the job:

```
import filecmp

test_filename = 'test.txt'
filename_list = ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt']
matched = any([_ for f_name f_name
               in filename_list 
               if filecmp.cmp(test_filename, f_name)])

if matched:            
    '{} and {} are equal'.format(filename_1, filename_2)
else:
    '{} and {} are NOT equal'.format(filename_1, filename_2)
```